# getting error while fetching a latest record from the table , error - Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

im trying to get the latest record or last upadated of the table , while fetching the record getting error saying - "Sequence contains more than one element". I tried with the Last(). still getting error. i need to to get the record in the json format as im using web api .

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GPS/GetGPS/{order}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetGPS(string order)
        {
            try
            {
                var gpsJson = "";
                using (TrackerEntities DB = new TrackerEntities ())
                {
                    var gps = DB.GPS.SingleOrDefault();// getting error here
                    gpsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gps);
                }
                var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, gpsJson);
                response.Content = new StringContent(gpsJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Change to `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Thanks, its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.SingleOrDefault` checks if there is **only one** item matching the condition, and throws if there are more.

If you simply want one item matching your condition, and don't care how many there can be, use `.FirstOrDefault`.